# Flickr API results cacheable?

Tags: api, flickr

When using the Flickr API for [getting informations on a photo](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html), I get a result looking like this:

```
<photo id="2733" secret="123456" server="12" isfavorite="0" license="3" rotation="90" originalsecret="1bc09ce34a" originalformat="png">
  <owner nsid="12037949754@N01" username="Bees" realname="Cal Henderson" location="Bedford, UK" />
  <title>orford_castle_taster</title>
  <description>hello!</description>
  [...]
</photo>
```

I am planning of caching the results in a database, however I am wondering **if some photo informations might not be cacheable on the long term**, especially the properties that are used for [building URLs](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html) (secret, server, farm-id...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discussions in the [Flickr API group](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/) would suggest that developers are successfully caching results.  I found [this post](http://www.allthegoodness.com/projects/map/flickr/flickrapi.php) (it's a bit old), which uses PHP, as well as [this more recent thread](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157628245659073/?search=cache).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea a "Flickr API" group existed on Flickr.

Answer (score 2):

I built an add-on for the ExpressionEngine CMS that used the Flickr API to pull images and their meta data into the CMS. The add-on cached most of the photo info, including the URLs which include the server, farm-id, etc.

Even after several months/years the URLs still work. So it doesn't appear those values change, at least not often.

One thing that did change awhile back was the suffix used to grab the specific sizes. I believe they added a few new sizes or changed the suffix on one or two.

Not to say they couldn't completely stir up the API next week though ;)